# "could not find a compatible repository" error on gitkraken repo

Tags: git, gitkraken

I've got a repository that I've had for years, using through GitKraken. I just used the CLI to assign a tag (using the code `git tag -a v0.7.1 -m "my version 0.7.1" ea27f3b3ab882e58cbb5995f5d8638a200676a43` then `git push --tags`) to the repo, and after that GitKraken will not open it. It says there's no repository there and asks if I want to initialize a new repo.

There are no problems with any of my other repos. Also, this repo works fine from the command line. I've tried deleting the folder manually, then cloning it again from github in the same place, but it didn't help. I've also tried `git reset --hard` locally, but to no use. Some google searching shows up things like long path names on deeply nested files, but I don't have that (and I'm on MacOS not Windows).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by Jake from the GitKraken team, on the GitKraken slack. I'll post the solution here if it may help someone in the future.

It appeared I had two malformed `ref`s in my repository, one to my `master` branch, the other to that `v0.7.1` tag I mentioned above. Deleting the tag, and the master branch, resolved the issue.

Comment: and how you found the solution? I mean i have a similar problem, but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: I deleted the master branch and the most recent tag

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when I tried to open a repository. When I tried to clone any repository, I got the message:

**"C:/Users/Username/.gitconfig": Access Denied**

I deleted the file, now both messages are gone.

Anyone who tries this should save the file elsewhere just in case.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this issue i used visual studio code, i opened it on the IDE and used the extension to commit all the files inside the folder.
Here is a link to the found solution[The link to a website](https://www.ernestech.com/articles/details/solved-gitkraken-%E2%80%9Ccould-not-find-a-compatible-repository%E2%80%9D/444)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue with GitKraken. It would keep presenting this "compatible repository" message even though it would load the repo and let me stage and browse commits. However, after about a minute, it would unload the repo and start trying to load it again, but just hang trying to load. Other tools (Giggle, `gitg`, git-gui, and the `git` CLI) all seemed to work just fine.

### A Solution

Digging a little deeper I found that, apparently, something got corrupted in my reflog. You can inspect the files in `.git/logs/refs/heads/*` and `.git/logs/refs/remotes/*/*` for any lines that look extremely unusual. All of the lines should look very much the same (from-hash, to-hash, timestamp, user, message, and so on). The corrupted lines in my log had loads of strange symbols and were like 4 time the length of the other lines. Very obvious.

I also found some zero byte objects, which should not be. Those are temp files that should have been filled with data or deleted but were not, for... reasons. They can safely be deleted.

```sh
find .git/objects -size 0 -type f -delete
```

### The Nuclear Option

To get my GitKraken working again, I need to go with the Nuclear Option.

Ok, if you are still having trouble and are *CERTAIN* that you do not need anything in your reflog, INCLUDING YOUR STASH, you can expire all of it now and clean up (garbage collect) the dangling refs:

```sh
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Well, I guess that there is an even more extreme step, in that you could delete the repo and re-clone but you would lose all local branches, stashes, and unpushed commits. I wasn't okay with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which happened for me seemingly out of the blue. After trying almost everything here, I moved the repo, did a fresh clone and it happened again after a few days.

It turned out that a script a colleague added to our project was creating a node_modules folder that would have the wrong permissions. They added a "npm install" command that would run in a docker container and files it wrote were owned by root. When I deleted it, all started to work again.